# Can't do textarea autocomplete

Tags: html, google-chrome, autocomplete, textarea

Input works perfect with autocomplete. But not textarea

```
<form action="/action_page.php" autocomplete="on">
   Input with autocompelte<input type="text" name="inputName"><br>
   Textarea with autocomplete<textarea name="textAreaName"></textarea>

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Fill in and submit the form, then reload the page to see how autocomplete works.

I've tried to use an example from https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_autocomplete but with textarea

Comment: Note: The autocomplete attribute works with the following <input> types: text, search, url, tel, email, password, datepickers, range, and color. this from w3schools link.

Comment: @wahdan according to spec it could be used also with textarea https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#inappropriate-for-the-control